# How to know if $\mathbb{P}(f(P_a) > \tau)$ is increasing or decreasing function of $P_a$ without actually computing it?

Tags: probability, functions, optimization, maxima-minima

**Problem Setup**
Consider the following optimization problem 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{P_{a},\lambda_{a}}{\text{maximize}}
& & P_{cov}(P_{a},\lambda_{a}) \\
& \text{subject to}
& &  0 \leq P_a \leq \min\{P_{a,max},\frac{\rho}{\lambda_a}\} \\
& & & 0 \leq \lambda_a \leq \lambda_{a,max} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
with 
$ P_{cov}(P_{a},\lambda_{a})=  P_{cov, a}(P_{a},\lambda_{a}) \, \mathcal{A}_a(P_{a},\lambda_{a}) + P_{cov, {\rm g}}(P_{a},\lambda_{a}) \, \mathcal{A}_ {\rm g}(P_{a},\lambda_{a})$ where 
\begin{equation}
P_{cov, {\rm g}}(P_{a},\lambda_{a})= \mathbb{P} \left(  \frac{P_{{\rm g}} {R_{{\rm g},0}}^{-\eta_{\rm g}} h_{{\rm g},0}}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P_{{\rm g}} {R_{{\rm g},i}}^{-\eta_{\rm g}} h_{{\rm g},i}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P_{a} {R_{a,i}}^{-\eta_a} h_{a,i}} > \tau \right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P_{cov, a}(P_{a},\lambda_{a})= \mathbb{P} \left(  \frac{P_{a} {R_{a,0}}^{-\eta_{a}} h_{{a},0}}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P_{{a}} {R_{{a},i}}^{-\eta_{a}} h_{{a},i}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P_{{\rm g}} {R_{{\rm g},i}}^{-\eta_{\rm g}} h_{{\rm g},i}} > \tau \right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}_a =\mathbb{P} \left(  P_{a} R_a^{-{\eta_a}} > P_{{\rm g}}  {R_{\rm g}}^{-\eta_{\rm g}}  \right),
\quad \text{and} \quad
\mathcal{A}_{\rm g} =\mathbb{P} \left(  P_{{\rm g}}  {R_{\rm g}}^{-\eta_{\rm g}}  > P_{a} R_a^{-{\eta_a}}  \right).
\end{equation}
where $R_{a,i}, R_{\rm g,i}, h_{a,i}, h_{\rm g,i}$ are all random variables and $P_a, P_{\rm g}, \eta_a, \eta_{\rm g}, \rho$ are all constants. $\lambda_a$ is a parameter that characterizes the pdf of $R_a$.

**Questions**

- Is $P_{cov}$ is an increasing function of $P_a$?

  - If yes, how to prove it without computing the probabilities?
  - If no, how can approach such an optimization problem? My
    initial approach was to utilize the note below, then perform a numerical search over a compact subset of candidate $\lambda_a$ values on the $P_a \lambda_a = \rho$ curve to find the optimum $\lambda_a$.

> **Note**
>
> If $P_{cov}$ is an increasing function of $P_a$ we can, without loss of optimality, reduce the problem to the following one-dimensional constrained optimization problem: 
>   \begin{equation*} 
> \begin{aligned} &
> \underset{\lambda_{a}}{\text{maximize}} 
> & &
> P_{cov}(\min\{P_{a,max},\frac{\rho}{\lambda_a}\},\lambda_{a}) \\
> & \text{subject to} 
> & &  0 \leq \lambda_a \leq \lambda_{a,max} \\
> \end{aligned} \tag{2}
> \end{equation*} since any $P^{\star}$ solving $(1)$ must achieve the power constraint with equality.

Comment: There is quite a number of variables here. Would you mind clarify the definitions of those variables, and the relationship between them, if any?

Comment: @BGM I did. Kindly see the updated post.

Comment: have you tried coupling? it's a general method allowing you to show certain probabilities are increasing (as a function of a certain parameter)

Comment: @mathworker21 No I haven't, I'll look into that.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Yes non-negative. $R_{a,i},R_{g,i},h_{a,i},h_{g,i}$ are random variables with pdfs having a support $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @BGM: Could you please provide some references for the method you call coupling?

Comment: @Hans actually that comment is not given by me, but maybe mathworker21 means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)

Comment: @mathworker21: Could you please provide some references for the method you call coupling? Thanks.

Comment: @Hans look at the two examples in the link BGM provided