# Is $f_1(X,c)=\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{X}{c} > \tau \right)$ is an increasing function of $c$?

Tags: probability, functions

Let $f(X,c)= f_{1}(X,c) \, \mathcal{A}_1(X,c) + f_{2}(X,c) \, \mathcal{A}_ {2}(X,c)$ with
$$
f_{1}=\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{X}{c} > \tau \right), 
\quad 
f_{2}=\mathbb{P} \left( c X > \tau \right),
\quad
\mathcal{A}_1 =\mathbb{P} \left(  \frac{X}{c} > 1  \right),
\quad \text{and} \quad
\mathcal{A}_2 = 1-\mathcal{A}_1.
$$
where $X$ is a random variable and $c>0$ is a constant.

Is $f(X,c)$ is an increasing function of $c$? Can we tell without computing the probabilities?

> **Note** This question is a shortened version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962757/how-to-know-if-a-probabilistic-function-is-increasing-or-decreasing-without-actu).

Comment: The answer depends on the sign of $c$. If $c >0$ then $P(\frac X c >\tau)$ is decreasing function and if If $c <0$ then $P(\frac X c >\tau)$ is an increasing function

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you elaborate more? How is it that you decide? Does it depend on $\frac{X}{c}$ only? And what if $c>0$?

Comment: Just use the fact that any distribution function is increasing. Note that $\frac X c >\tau$ is equivalent to $X>c\tau$ if $c >0$ and it is equivalent to $X<c\tau$ if $c <0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy by distribution function, do you mean that the cdf, $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$, is an increasing function of $x$ and the ccdf, $\mathbb{P}(X > x)$, is a decreasing function of $x$? Then, for my case, $\mathbb{P} ( \frac{X}{c} > \tau)$ is a decreasing function of $c$ and $\mathbb{P}( c X > \tau)$ is an increasing function of $c$?

Comment: It is a decreasing function of $c$ on $(0,\infty)$ and an increasing function on $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy which one is that? I’m sorry I’m not really following.